# Edição sem nexo de resposta aprovada na fila de analise

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, edições-sugeridas, filas-de-análise

Tenho aqui uma edição na resposta à pergunta «[Fazer botão <a> alterar href=" " a cada novo acesso em determinada página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157907/fazer-bot%C3%A3o-a-alterar-href-a-cada-novo-acesso-em-determinada-p%C3%A1gina)» que foi aprovada, que não faz sentido nenhum, embora entre mim e o editor até houvesse concordância para a edição ela foi aprovada na fila, alguém me poderá explicar o porquê?

Aqui fica a aprovação:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/83498

Que fique claro que esta publicação não tem o intuito de acusar ninguém, reli agora e tive a noção que poderá parecer uma acusação, a ideia aqui é mais alertar para que tenham cuidado com as aprovações na fila de analise.

Comment: Parece que a edição foi um engano (paste no campo errado?), e a aprovação foram mais dois "enganos"...

Comment: @bfavaretto a edição não foi bem um engano, eu e o AP estávamos a conversar e eu sabia da edição. O problema é como é que é aprovada, na analise, uma edição como essa, preocupa-me mais por ser uma resposta, alterando a resposta por completo...

Comment: Ah, entendi. E sim, a aprovação é grave. Ou eles nem olharam a edição, ou têm uma concepção totalmente equivocada sobre o que deve ser editado no site.

Comment: @bfavaretto por isso é que vim a correr fazer esta pergunta...

Comment: Esse tipo de aprovação é bem comum, estou cansado de listar isso no chat, mas depois que um editor achou ruim comigo, mesmo estando errado, passei a ignorar. Algumas aprovações parecem feitas no modo "automático". Já até comentei lá sobre fazermos um levantamento sobre edições equivocadas, mas um debate desse tipo só geraria intrigas e, ao menos eu, não quero assumir esse risco.

Comment: Fique registrado que os moderadores podem suspender usuários das filas de análise e do próprio site, se julgarem que está havendo abuso.

Comment: @bfavaretto e como podemos reportar isso a vocês, quando detectarmos mau uso da fila de analise, sem que tenhamos que nos expor publicamente e sofrer represálias?

Comment: @diego Sinalizando a postagem em questão

Comment: @bfavaretto me referi quando for detectado multiplos casos.

Comment: Sinalize uma delas e explique o caso no texto da sinalização.